# Value does not change outside $.ajax.done() scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to permanently change some values from inside the `$.ajax.done()` scope, so that it is available to other parts of my code outside this scope. The variable `duplicate` is a global variable within a module I have written and I want to be able to use the updated boolean value in other functions after running `done()`.

The function `duplicateFile` is set up to return a block of `$.ajax({ url:... });` code.

```
// Callback function
duplicateError = function() {
        console.log(duplicate); // prints 'true' if a duplicate is found
        if (duplicate) {
            errors.create("duplicateFile");
        }
    };

// AJAX call
duplicateFile(fileData).done(duplicateError);
```

If a duplicate is found after running the AJAX call, `console.log` prints `true`. But if I try to call `console.log` after the AJAX function call as follows, the value is `false` regardless:

```
duplicateFile(fileData).done(duplicateError);
console.log(duplicate); // always prints 'false'
```

Is there any way to work around this and get the `duplicate` value to change permanently after calling the request? I know I could set `async: false` in the AJAX request, but I would like to avoid that.

**EDIT:** `duplicate` is getting changed in the callback function that is passed to the `success` method in the`$.ajax({ url:... })` .

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Where is `duplicate` getting changed? It is not clear through your code. The most probable cause of this behaviour is the asynchronous nature of Ajax.

Comment: @puelo `duplicate` is getting changed in the callback function that is passed to the `success` method in the`$.ajax({ url:... })` . I'll update the original post with that.

Comment: @helllomatt I am using callbacks in my code as shown above, but I'm not sure what's going wrong. If I'm modifying code (setting values, etc) in my callbacks, why isn't it becoming permanent?

Comment: @RishadBharucha did you check out hellomatt's link? The problem is that the success function is executed when the Ajax request is finished. Ajax is asynchronous and this means, that the `console.log` gets executed before the Ajax request is finished (most of the times). It is not a problem of a value becoming permanent, it is a question of execution order.